# SQL Inner Join - retrieving wrong ids

Tags: php, sql

i try to retrieve datas from my database with following sql.

```
select mc.ADD_DATE,mc.MOVIE_ID,mc.COMMENT,m.ID,m.NAME 
from MOVIE_COMMENT as mc 
INNER Join MOVIE as m ON  m.ID=mc.MOVIE_ID  
WHERE user_ID = " . $getUser->id . " 
    and STAT='onayli' 
ORDER BY mc.ADD_DATE DESC LIMIT " . $commentCount . "
```

I use Inner join because i also retrieve movie names from another table.

```
mc = MOVIE_COMMENT table
m = MOVIE Table
```

My problem is that when i try to retrieve mc ids, it gives me the movie ids why?

Comment: 'select mc.ADD_DATE,mc.MOVIE_ID,mc.COMMENT,m.ID,m.NAME ',  shouldn't there be a MC.IDS or soemthing similar?

Comment: Note that if you add `mc.ID` there, `m.ID` won't be returned. If you need both use an alias, like this: `...mc.ID AS movie_comment_ID, m.ID AS movie_ID...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the Movie_Comment IDs, you need to return the mc.ID field.

```
SELECT mc.ID as Movie_Comment_ID, mc.ADD_DATE, mc.MOVIE_ID, mc.COMMENT, m.ID, m.NAME 
FROM MOVIE_COMMENT as mc 
INNER Join 
MOVIE as m 
ON  m.ID = mc.MOVIE_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `m.ID` in your select list. You probably want `mc.ID`.

Comment: try puting both `mc.ID as MCID` and `m.ID as MID` in the same select clause and see if there's a difference in results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `m.ID` with `mc.ID` in your select clause?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the ids from the MOVIE_COMMENT table as mc.MOVIE_ID.
Thus, when you try to access there (e.g., from PHP), you need to access MOVIE_ID.
Asking for ID will return m.ID, the ids from the MOVIE table.